# Code is showing (TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable)

Tags: python, list

[(starting code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMkzA.png) My code is showing (TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable) error even the variable I am using is contains some value. [This is the code I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z75CU.png)

Comment: Please don't force people to click on links to view code, especially one that are just pictures of your code. You can include the code in the question. Read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in how you are appending values to your list `users_cards`.

You have written `users_cards = users_cards.append(random.choice(cards))`.

The append function automatically updates the object so the code should read: `users_cards.append(random.choice(cards))` (no need for the `users_cards =` bit)

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Your `user_cards` is None. You need an iterable there (list, tuple etc) because you've used `sum` function on that. Make sure `user_cards` is initialized.

Comment: I did initialized the variables. See the starting code